# VMware Workstation cannot sync with disk before abort. Disk *.vmdk may be inconsistent

Tags: vmware

I have a VMware image on a external hard disk, but the power supply shut off abruptly. The next time I tried to start that image, the image started booting into the OS (Windows XP), but would subsequently hang, resulting in the below image:

[image]

When I forced the VMware software to close, I got this message:

> VMware Workstation cannot sync with
>   disk before abort. Disk *.vmdk may be
>   inconsistent.

Here's the extra message:

> Operation on File *.vmdk failed. If the file reside on a remote file
>   system, please make sure that your network connection and the server
>   where this disk resides are functioning properly. If the file resides
>   on removable media, reattach the media.

And when I examine the directory of the VMWare image, I found that there are a lot of funny named files and folders, and I presume that there are the local copy of my residue OS.

How can I fix this problem so that my OS image can load again? In other words, how to recover from this power failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.

It's because the disk where the VM image resides in is corrupted. If I go to

> start->control panel-.Administrative
>   tools->even viewer->system

I will find this message:

> The device, \Device\Harddisk1\D, has a
>   bad block.

This indicates that there are bad sectors.

In this case, the only solution seems to be changing the hard disk all together.

Comment: I need to wait for 21 hours before I can do that. Duh!

Comment: @Graviton, So what's the fix?

Comment: @Pacerier, In this case, the only solution seems to be changing the hard disk all together.